# Do I need to use `next` or `store.dispatch` in my middleware

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm building my async middleware from which I want to dispatch several actions. Here is how it looks at the moment:

```
const [ requestType, successType, failureType ] = types;
next({type: requestType});

return call().then(
    result => {
        return next({
            result,
            type: successType
        })
    },
    error =>  {
        // I want to dispath the `sendNotification()` action here
        // to add item to notifications center
        // should I use `next` or `store.dispath`?

        //this way?
        store.dispath(failedNotification);
        //or this way?
        next(failedNotification);

        return next({
            type: failureType,
            error: error.message || 'Something bad happened',
            errorType: error.errorType
        })
    }
)
```

My question is in these comments in the code above:

> ```
>       // I want to dispath the `sendNotification()` action here
>       // to add item to notifications center
>       // should I use `next` or `store.dispath`?
> ```

The reason I'm asking is because from what I understood of `applyMiddleware` implementation details from [here](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), `next()` will pass an action through the remaining chain of middlewares, while `store.dispatch` will path through the entire chain of middlewares including the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would use `store.dispatch()`, the dispatch will trigger your middleware again and call `call()` once more. Sometimes it may cause the infinite loop, so calling `next()` looks here a better choice.